# PHP preg_replace with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to add some language support to my site like mydomain.com/en/ mydomain.com/fr/ mydomain.com/de/

and I want to redirect every page to its equivalent in the selected language like:
mydomain.com/en/contact/ to mydomain.com/fr/contact/

How to do it using preg_replace() ?

I just want to get the regex like *mydomain.com/(en|fr|de)/contact/?
Can you please give me the right regex for that

This is my function:

```
function ch_lang($lang) {
    $curr_url   = str_replace('//', '/', SITE_URL . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
        $new_url = preg_replace('|/(?:en|fr|de)/|', "/$lang/", $curr_url);
    } else {
        $new_url = str_replace('.local/', '.local' . $lang, $curr_url);
    }
    echo $new_url;
}
```

Comment: This type of thing is usually done with rewrite rules, not in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar, its to create links in the page so I think it's done with php

Comment: Your question says you want to redirect, not create links on the page.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry maybe I didn't ask it the right way

Comment: Question titles are supposed to summarize, not broadly relist tags.

Comment: What's the relationship between `$lang` and `$_GET['lang']`? Shouldn't you use the latter in the replacement?

Comment: it's the same as it $_GET['lang'] is retrieved from ?lang=en done using htaccess rewrite

Answer (score 2):

```
$link = 'mydomain.com/en/contact';
$lang_link = preg_replace('|/(?:en|fr|de)/|', "/$selected_lang/", $link);
```

Comment: but what if "en" is "fr" or "de" I think it must be something like en|fr|de

Comment: Where are these links coming from? Why don't you put `en` in all the original links, so you can easily replace it with the selected language?

Comment: Even better, initialize them like `mydomain.com/LANG/contact`, so it's more obvious that it's a placeholder.

Comment: the problem is that if the user changes the lang from the default "en"  to "fr" and then he decides to try "de" (he will be coming from "fr" not "en")

Comment: How would the user's selected language affect the value of the variable that you're doing the substitution on? I'll ask again: where is the link coming from? Are you talking about `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer to show how to match multiple languages.

Comment: yes, I have a little function that will output the new url from the current url, where the current url is one of two types, the first is without the "/en/" or "/fr/" and it defaults to English, and the second is with one of the three.

Comment: function ch_lang($lang) {
 $curr_url   = str_replace('//', '/', SITE_URL . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
     $new_url = preg_replace({***}, {***}, $curr_url);
 } else {
     $new_url = str_replace('.local/', '.local' . $lang, $curr_url);
 }
 echo $new_url;
    }

Comment: Don't try to put multi-line code in comments, because they can't be formatted.